# How to do load more to collectionview ?

Tags: ios, swift, pagination, collectionview

I have a api that supports pagination.

```
"pagination":{  
  "total":355,
  "totalPages":10,
  "page":1,
  "nextPage":2,
  "nextPageUrl":"http://api..................?page=2" }
```

my aim is that to add nextPageUrl's images to my collectionview. 
So how can i do this ?

**Any advice or code sample ?** I am new at swift. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a button to the end of the collection view so everytime the user presses this button, you make the call to the server again but for the next page.
Then you append the received data to the old one and you call collectionView.reloadData. You can also do it without a button, just when the user arrives to the end of the collection view, it starts automatically.

You can do the second one that way:

```
if (CGRectGetMaxY(scrollView.bounds) == scrollView.contentSize.height) {
    callToServer()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it automatic, when the user scrolls near the bottom of the collection view, You can trigger the request to load more on a  global thread, than when ready reload Your collection view with the new data. This approach needs to be tailored for Your needs of course. Here is pseudo code example (in swift because of the question's tags) :

```
class VideoList {
  var dataModel: [SomeDataModelType]
  var isLoadingMore = false

  // .. variables and methods

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,  willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      let preloadingTreashold = Int(dataModel.count * 0.75)
      let threasholdReached = indexPath.item >= preloadingTreashold
      let reachedLastElement = indexPath.item == dataModel.count - 1
      if !isLoadingMore {
        loadMore()
      }
  }

// Example function for load more, a little bit pseudocode.
// The idea is only to illustrate the case.
  func loadMore {   
    isLoadingMore = true

    // distpatch loading on global queue, because we don't
    // want to block the main thread
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
      // if your data model is a class You may need to copy it
      // before You alter it, because otherwise, a user interaction
      // can trigger an out of bounds exception or some other kind
      // of nasty problem
      var tmpDataModel = dataModel.copy()

      // load new data model
      var extendedDataModel = loadMore(to: tmpDataModel)

      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // callback for loaid more completed or reloadData call
        isLoadingMore = false        
      }
    } 
  }

  //  other methods ...
}
```